# Install python 3 on bluehost

Tags: bluehost

I'm trying to set up my Bluehost account with python 3 so that I can use it with a flask site that I've created locally.  I found instructions on how to do this at: http://multiactivelife.com/articles/install-python3-on-bluehost.  I made it most of the way through, but I unfortunately get the following error when I try to run `make install`:

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python3.7m': Read-only file system
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1
```

I have tried to chmod to the bin directory (0755) but with no luck.  Any idea on how I can get write access to my bin folder so that I can install python 3 on bluehost?

Comment: I've just started following the same path as you, and read the same encouraging article.  Do add an answer if you've found out how to do it.

I hope you have, and that all went well....

Answer (score 3):

From the Bluehost website:

"Note: In order to install python locally, you will need to be added to the Compiler group. Please contact Support to request you be added to the Compiler group before proceeding."

https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/python-installation